# Can there be an upper bound on the Borel rank of the preimages of Borel sets under a surjective Borel map?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets, measurable-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be standard Borel spaces, $Y$ uncountable, and $f : X \to Y$ a surjective Borel map. Is it possible that there is a countable ordinal $\alpha$ such that for each Borel set $B \subseteq Y$, the Borel rank of the set $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq X$ is at most $\alpha$?

Comment: My previous comment misunderstood the question.  "For each Borel set $B$..."

Comment: @GeraldEdgar  Looks like we need our combined efforts to both read the whole question!

Comment: Hopefully I can make a sensible comment this time, but I believe that there are no examples if $f$ is injective. Because in that case $f(U)$ is Borel for all open $U\subseteq X$

Comment: To clarify, is "Polish space" intended in the question instead of "standard Borel space"? The Borel rank of a set depends on which topology is used to define the Borel sets. If $X$ and $Y$ are Polish, then we can put a finer Polish topology on $X$ with the same Borel sets in which $f$ continuous (see Theorem 13.11 of Kechris's *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*). Since the new topology on $X$ is finer, the Borel rank of any $f^{-1}(B)$ can only go down, so if for every continuous function $f$, the sets $f^{-1}(B)$ have unbounded Borel rank, this also holds for all Borel maps $f$.

Comment: @RobertFurber: Here $X$ is a Borel subset of a Polish space $Z$, and Borel rank of a subset $A \subseteq X$ is meant to be the Borel rank of $A$ as a subset of $Z$. (I am fine assuming $Y$ to be Polish.)

Comment: @ArkadiPredtetchinski Thanks for clarifying. This case is reducible to the case where $X$ is Polish by taking a finer Polish topology on $Z$, with the same Borel sets, in which $X$ is clopen.

Comment: @RobertFurber: The reduction to continuous $f$ helps.  Exercise 8.8 (ii) of Kechris claims that for continuous $f$ with uncountable image, there is a Cantor set on which $f$ is injective.  It's right after the Baire category theorem so maybe the proof is not too hard (I didn't try it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:  Construct a Cantor set $E \subseteq X$ on which $f$ is bijective.  Then $f$ is a homeomorpism of $E$ onto $f(E)$, and $f(E)$ has Borel subsets of arbitrarily high rank.

Comment: @ArkadiPredtetchinski: "Cantor set" means it's compact, right?  So the Borel rank of $f^{-1}(B) \cap E$ is at most 1 greater than that of $f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: I think I see how to build such a Cantor set by reducing to the case that $Y$ is perfect and building up a tree of open sets with disjoint closures, like in the usual proof that every perfect Polish space contains a Cantor set. Is this what is intended, or is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Comment: @RobertFurber ...Yes, that is the method I had in mind.  Choose complete metrics, and make sure the diameters in your tree go to zero.

Comment: @RobertFurber you can also reduce to continuous $f$ as in the comments under the question and show that $f$ is injective on a generic element of $K(X)$ (and a generic element of $K(X)$ is perfect). Of course this is more work than your approach, but you get a stronger result in the end

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti This seems (from context) to be the method of proof intended in Kechris's exercise mentioned by Nate Eldredge. This looks like a useful fact to know.